# A tricky question in scheme continuation definition

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop, continuations

R5rs says

> The continuation represents an entire (default) future for the computation".

So basically in the following code:

```
(define x (call/cc (lambda (c) c)))
(display "hello\n")
(display "world\n")
(x 4)
(display x)
```

I tried several implementations, all of them output

```
hello
world
4
```

It seems in this example the continuation captured by call/cc limited its scope for the first top level expression only. That likes `(define x ?)`.

I though based on r5rs, when `(x 4)` is executed, execution will jump back to the beginning definition form and finish the assignment. Then it would continue to run the subsequent two display expressions and run `(x 4)` which would report an error since x will no longer be a procedure.

Comment: If you captured the sequence of the outermost expressions and definitions on the stack, it would mean each captured continuation would restart the program in the moment when you restore it, and you do not want this.  Anyways, topmost-level of a running scheme *does not have empty stack*, but a stack that contains the shutdown continuation.  I think you should continue working with scheme, if you feel something "tricky" in your question, you should go on working with and you will clarify alone this kind of questions.

Comment: I believe there's an implied "of the expression where it is captured" after that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Your expectations are correct. The problem is that the REPL executes each expression separately, as if you had pressed ENTER between each one. If you wrap them in a `begin`, it works as you expect.

```
$ scheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.5.8
Copyright 1984-2022 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (begin
   (define x (call/cc (lambda (c) c)))
   (display "hello\n")
   (display "world\n")
   (x 4)
   (display x))
hello
world
hello
world
Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure 4
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

Comment: Know that `begin` in top level might become unrolled. A better version would be to use an empty `let` and have all the code in the body.

Comment: @sylwester I'm not sure what you mean by "unrolled", but you're right that `let ()` will work too, as long as `x` doesn't need to be referenced outside the `let`.